How to send form-data to WebToLead or WebToCase APIs?
Instead of the usual approach of implementing web-to-lead, I wanted to experiment with doing a POST to the web-to-lead endpoint itself that one can find via the Web-to-Lead Setup option in Salesforce.
By getting the endpoint from this and then doing a POST with string parameters, this creates a lead in my org; which is great.
However, from a security perspective, it would be even better if I could do this with putting the params in the body (form-data option).
However, the form-data option does not work. Presumably, this is just how the Salesforce servlet is configured and there's nothing I can do about this to get it to accept form-data?

Don't use form-data, but rather x-www-form-urlencoded, if you want to take this path. Here's an example from Postman:

Here, you can see that I specify parameters in the body, and this does create the lead in Salesforce.
In fact, the default generated HTML doesn't even need the parameters, this very request works.
Url: https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:

oid=00D...&first_name=Brian&last_name=Fear&company=Myself

Obviously, my oid is redacted to try and prevent spam in my dev org.
The only reason why you'd want to use form-data is if you were uploading files, which you're not, because Web-to-Lead doesn't support that.

Thanks as always, sfdcfox - I should have tried that option myself! I shall redact my throw away dev org Id but was somewhat curious to see if anyone does try to spam it anyway :)
